Is there a difference in js script in HTML vs external js script?
this is my first time posting so I might not be posting in the correct method. I'm trying to display the current value for a slider via an output. It doesn't work when I put my script externally, but it does when I put it in the HTML file, so I'm confused.
**Here's my initial code: **
(index.html)
<script src="js.js"></script>

<label for="max-invite">Select maximum number of invitations</label>
        <input type="range" name="max-invite" id="max-invite" min="1" max="30" value="10" step="1">
        <output class="invite-output" for="max-invite"></output>

(js.js)
const invite = document.querySelector('#max-invite');
      const output = document.querySelector('.invite-output');

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        output.textContent = invite.value;
      }) 

      invite.addEventListener('input', function() {
        output.textContent = invite.value;
      });

... and there is no display for the output.
I pasted the script direct onto the HTML file and it worked.
Is there a difference? Is there something I need to change to make the external script method work? TIA.


In the HTML you show, the script tag is before the rest of the HTML it tries to manipulate. This means the JS code would run before the HTML exists. This should produce errors in the console. If you pasted the JS code in the same place as the tag, you should still get the same errors. If you pasted it after the HTML, it would have worked. 2. You should also make sure the path to the file is correct. This should also generate errors.


XY problem... To answer your question: Yes there is a difference. The main difference is that external JS can be reused by other HTML files. external JS can be cached and reduced loading times on the 2nd load onwards. But that will not help you as you have a different issue than you asked about.

Indeed, my question was answered in that post, but I didn't know that was the issue. I learnt about defer today. Thank you to everyone who helped.

If you simply used the same script and it didn't work, check your path.
<script src="./js.js"></script>

or
<script src="{DIR}/js.js"></script>

